# Date and time conversion according to Zone using Flex3

Tags: apache-flex, datetime, formatting, timezone, country

i am sending the date and time in ( mm/dd/yyyy hh:mm) this format from india to australia( i am booking a date and time for future), for the user in australia it should show him according to his local time. As australia is 5 hrs and 30 mins past to india. how to do it using flex3.

Answer (score 0):

Flex has *no* timezone calculation support built-in (you can get your local clock's offset and convert between UTC time and local time and that's basically it), your best bet would be to do the conversion via a server-call (with Joda handling the timezone calculations, which includes DST offsets).

Comment: Is there any way to find out in which time zone the flex application is opened, through web browser? basically my problem is i have chat application running as desktop and web application connected with red5. i am sending dateand time from one user to other. through red5 the user is going to receive exactly the same date and time . i would like to convert that received date according to time zone? both the users may exist in any country? how to find the country or time zone of both the users ? Any help is appreciated.

Comment: you can find the time zone of the current browser using Date.getTimezoneOffset()

Answer (score 0):

First, use the [Date](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/Date.html) class. Second, use UTC values when sending dates (see getUTC family of methods). So when you receive a date, you'll know it is in UTC so you can set up a Date instance with those UTC values (see setUTC family of methods). The class will automatically do the timezone calculations for you and when you present it to the user it will be in their timezone.